# Spring - Create an instance of one class using the factory method of another class

Tags: spring

I am using Apache Ignite in my Spring project.  I want to create an instance of org.apache.ignite.Ignite within my application context using xml configuration.  One of the way to create the Ignite object is by using org.apache.ignite.Ignition#start method.  My question is, how can i use bean xml configuration to create an instance of Ignite from Ignition#start.

```
<!-- Implements Ignite interface -->
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal">

</bean>

<!-- Returns instance of Ignite as org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal -->
<bean id="ignitionIgniteKernal" class="org.apache.ignite.Ignition" factory-method="start">
    <constructor-arg ref="refToConfig" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the spring documentation, the "ignitionIgniteKernal" bean definition above is exactly how you would create an instance of org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.  Ref:

> If the "class" attribute is present, the factory method will be a
>   static    method on the class specified by the "class" attribute on this
>   bean  definition. Often this will be the same class as that of the
>   constructed   object - for example, when the factory method is used as
>   an alternative    to a constructor. However, it may be on a different
>   class. In that case,  the created object will *not* be of the class
>   specified in the "class"  attribute. This is analogous to FactoryBean
>   behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Spring cache Manager.

http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/spring-caching

As per documentation

> The embedded node can be started by SpringCacheManager itself. In this case you will need to provide a path to Ignite configuration XML file or IgniteConfiguration bean via configurationPath or configuration properties respectively (see examples below). Note that setting both is illegal and results in IllegalArgumentException.

So the application context brings up the cache and then spring cache manager manages the cache via annotation or explicit addition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aravind.  Your response enables me to do what i needed which is having an instance of Ignite within my class code.  But the outstanding question still remains.  How can i create an instance of one class using the factory method of another.